# JSF 1.2 dynamic sort

Tags: sorting, jsf, dynamic

i have following question.
Is it possible to do a dynamic sort with jsf 1.2 ?
I have a List of type SelectItem. I can already add and remove entries.
Now I want to sort dynamic in the Browser via Drag and Drop or with an arrow.
I know it is possible to sort with Collection.sort and a Comparator, but this wants to compare 2 entries by id and sort ASC or DESC.

Got someone an idea?

I'm using JSF 1.2 without Prime,-Rich,-Ice Faces.

Answer (score 0):

I made now a button for moveUp and MoveDown.
I have a List for the Selected Item and the full List
I iterate both List and cast the value of my SelectItem and compare both Values.

Here is the Code I used

```
public void moveUp() {
    List<String> list1New = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String list1value : list1) {
        Integer value2= new Integer(list1value );

        for (SelectItem item : list2) {
            Integer value = (Integer) item.getValue();

            if (value.equals(value2- 1)) {
                item.setValue(value + 1);
            } else if (value.equals(value2)) {
                item.setValue(value2 - 1);

                list1New.add(String.valueOf(list1 - 1));
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    list1.remove(0);
    list1.add(list1new.get(0));
    list2.sort(new SelectItemComparator());
}
```

I also used my own Comparator like u see.

Hope it helps!